# GetType and typeof

Tags: c#

```
Type typeThing = gumballMachine.GetState().GetType();
if (typeThing == typeof(NoQuarterState)) { ... }


IState state;
public IState GetState() {
    return state;
}


public class NoQuarterState : IState { ... }
```

I'm using a gumballMachine app from Ch10 of Head First Design Patterns.  [full code here](http://www.programgood.net/2011/11/28/StateMachineAndGumballConsoleWinFormTests.aspx) This works.

Problem:  typeThing above smells!  Is there a better way?

Comment: I am not aware of any other way to get the type of an instance, except with GetType().  There are checks you can do, though, via the `is` and `as` operators, to determine if it's the type you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`is` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
if(gumballMachine.GetState() is NoQuarterState)
{
   //..
}
```

This of course would result in `true` for all types that inherit from `NoQuarterState` as well though. Based on your example this shouldn't be a problem.

The question is why do you have to distinguish by type in the first place? Usually that's a sign that a better design is in order, i.e. maybe the the strategy pattern or another use of polymorphism could help.

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify the GumballMachine class you could use an enum instead of types:

```
public enum StateEnum
{
   NoQuarterState,
   SomeOtherState
}

StateEnum GetState { get; }

if(gumballMachine.GetState.Equals(StateEnum.NoQuarterState)) { ... }
```

Comment: I'd consider combining the existing code and your enum technique - add a property of type StateEnum to IState .

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
  object typeThing = gumballMachine.GetState();
  //1st way
  if (typeThing is NoQuarterState) {...}
  //Or 2nd way
  if ((typeThing as NoQuarterState)!=null) {...}
```